# Restricting text area content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a plugin in Jquery to restrict the text entered inside a text area, depending upon the font-size and font-family?

I know there is a maximum length attribute but I want something dynamic, depending upon the font-size and font-family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function($){ 
    $.fn.extend({  
        limitText: function() {
            var interval, f;
            var self = $(this);

            $(this).focus(function(){
                interval = window.setInterval(substring,100);
            });

            $(this).blur(function(){
                clearInterval(interval);
                checkfont();
            });
       function checkfont(){ 
           var font_family = self.css('font-family');
           var font_size = self.css('font-size');

           if(font_family != "Tahoma" && font_size <= "13"){
           // You can configure according to you need in condition
           $(self).val($(self).val().substring(0,limit));
           }

       }
       substring();
       } 
   }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't want it to have a specific limit. I want that limit to vary depending upon the font-size or font-family.